# how to search with a keyword or title

Tags: node.js, express

Anyone might have an idea how can I make this endpoint to work for example on search of "Algebra" title all the titles with "algebra" keyword would show up?

```js
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;

    if(name === 'algebra') {
      console.log(
        axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/23150699.json')
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.title)
          })
      )
    } else {
      console.log('not deep')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API you are fetching data from doesn't have an endpoint to return a search query. If I were you, I would try to fetch all the items and then search for the items that match that specific search term. I tried reading the API docs but I didn't find any endpoint that returned all the items at once. It seems like the only thing you can fetch is particular items with their id.